# Using a custom toolchain in bazel

Tags: c++, compilation, cross-compiling, bazel, include-path

I'm using instructions at [cc-toolchain-config](https://bazel.build/tutorials/cc-toolchain-config) documentation to build a bazel project using a custom toolchain.

At some point the tutorial instructs adding the following

```
cxx_builtin_include_directories = [ # NEW
        "/usr/lib/llvm-9/lib/clang/9.0.1/include",
        "/usr/include",
      ],
```

to the arguments of `create_cc_toolchain_config_info`.

I don't understand why `/usr/include` is being added here. Why is this required? In fact why does this even make sense e.g. when the toolchain is a cross-compiler where `/usr/include` of the build machine is completely irrelevant? For example I expected to see something like `$TOOLCHAIN_INSTALL_DIR/include/c++/v1` instead of `/usr/include`.

Comment: It doesn’t have to be `/usr/include` it’s just an example list of default include directories to search. Use whatever makes sense for your tool chains.

Comment: But excluding /usr/include (and with or without including dir containing iostream from my toolchain) I get a build error which shows including iostream references `/usr/include`:
```
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'file.cpp':
  '/usr/include/c++/12.1.0/iostream'
  '/usr/include/c++/12.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h'
  '/usr/include/c++/12.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h'
...
```